# Using custom mapbox tiles with angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, mapbox

Good examples are very hard (better yet, impossible) to find on how to use angular-leaflet-directive with Mapbox, though Mapbox says we can fallback to it. No support, no documentation.

Anyway, plugin works well when loading basic mapbox tiles but when it comes to custom tiles, the mapbox:// scheme just won't load.

A plunker would be mad appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try creating a "classic" project and use that api. https://www.mapbox.com/studio/classic/

Comment: Thanks steven, I've found how to integrate a custom map using http://path_to_tile.

Comment: Would you mind writing a complete answer, as I am looking for a solution too.